# Using the MVP pattern and OO principles

Tags: java, design-patterns, mvp, single-responsibility-principle, open-closed-principle

I'm trying to apply the principles of object-oriented programming in a scenario that uses the MVP pattern.
I got 4 solutions, and the last two I liked more.
However most of the solutions break down certain principles as SRP, IOC / DIP, Open-Closed Principle, etc..

Briefly, I want the viewer and the presenter may have an optional behavior. This behavior allows the viewer to has a window or to be contained in one panel.
In my opinion the viewer should have knowledge of the JFrame and listeners, the windowed presenter should perform some additional actions when the viewer supports the chosen window behavior.

Can you help me find the best design for this situation? I believe that the examples will make clear the need.

**Solution 1** - Adapter like

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConcreteWindowedView view = new ConcreteWindowedView();
        Presentable presenter = new ConcreteWindowedPresenter(view);
        presenter.present();
    }
}

public interface Presentable {
    public void present();
}

public interface Viewable {
    public void view();
}

public class ConcreteView implements Viewable {
    private Container container;
    public ConcreteView(Container container) {
        this.container = container;
    }
    public void view() {
        // Configure UI (TextBox, Buttons) inside container;
    }
}

public class ConcretePresenter implements Presentable {
    private Viewable viewable;
    public ConcretePresenter(Viewable viewable) {
        this.viewable = viewable;
    }
    public void present() {
        // Configure presenter;
        viewable.view();
        // Register UI action listener
    }
}

public class ConcreteWindowedView implements Viewable {
    private ConcreteView contentView;
    private JFrame frame;
    public ConcreteWindowedView() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        contentView = new ConcreteView(frame.getContentPane());
    }
    public void view() {                
        contentView.view();
    }  
    public void addWindowListerner() {

    }    
}

public class ConcreteWindowedPresenter implements Presentable {
    private ConcreteWindowedView windowedView;
    private ConcretePresenter concretePresenter;
    public ConcreteWindowedPresenter(ConcreteWindowedView windowedView) {
        this.windowedView = windowedView;
        this.concretePresenter = new ConcretePresenter(windowedView);
    }
    public void present() {
        // Configure presenter
        concretePresenter.present();
        // Register window listeners
        this.windowedView.addWindowListerner();
    }
}
```

**Solution 2** - Using inheritance

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConcreteWindowedView view = new ConcreteWindowedView();
        Presentable presenter = new ConcreteWindowedPresenter(view);
        presenter.present();
    }
}

public interface Viewable {
    public void view();
}
public interface Presentable {
    public void present();
}
public class ConcreteView implements Viewable {
    protected Container container;
    protected ConcreteView() {
    }
    public ConcreteView(Container container) {
        this.container = container;
    }
    public void view() {
        // Configure UI (TextBox, Buttons) inside container;
    }
}

public class ConcreteWindowedView extends ConcreteView {
    public JFrame frame;
    public ConcreteWindowedView() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        container = frame.getContentPane();
    }
    public void view() {
        // Configure view
        super.view();
        // Show JFrame
    }
    public void addWindowListerner() {
    }
}

public class ConcretePresenter implements Presentable {
    Viewable viewable;
    public ConcretePresenter(Viewable viewable) {
        this.viewable = viewable;
    } 
    public void present() {
        // Configure presenter;
        viewable.view();
        // Register UI action listener
    }
}

public class ConcreteWindowedPresenter extends ConcretePresenter {
    private ConcreteWindowedView concreteWindowedView;
    public ConcreteWindowedPresenter(ConcreteWindowedView viewable) {
        super(viewable);
        this.concreteWindowedView = viewable;
    }
    public void present() {
        // Configure presenter
        super.present();
        // Register window listeners
        this.concreteWindowedView.addWindowListerner();
    }
}
```

**Solution 3** - Using a window handler

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Viewable view = new ConcreteView();
        Presentable presenter = new ConcretePresenter(view, new WindowViewHandler(view));
        presenter.present();
    }
}

public interface Viewable {
    public void view();
    public void setContainer(Container container);
}

public interface Presentable {
    public void present();
}

public class ConcreteView implements Viewable {
    Container container;
    public ConcreteView() {
    }
    public ConcreteView(Container container) {
        this.container = container;
    }        
    public void view() {
        if (container == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("Container not set.");
        // Configure UI (TextBox, Buttons) inside container;
    }  
    public void setContainer(Container container) {
        this.container = container;
    }
}

public class ConcretePresenter implements Presentable {
    Viewable viewable;
    WindowViewHandler windowHandler;
    public ConcretePresenter(Viewable viewable) {
        this.viewable = viewable;
    }
    public ConcretePresenter(Viewable viewable, WindowViewHandler windowHandler) {
        this(viewable);
        this.windowHandler = windowHandler;
    }   
    public void present() {        
        // Configure presenter        
        if (windowHandler != null)
            windowHandler.addWindowListerner();

        this.viewable.view();                    
    }
}

public class WindowViewHandler {

    Viewable viewable;
    JFrame frame;

    public WindowViewHandler(Viewable viewable) {
        this.viewable = viewable;
        initWindow();
    }

    private void initWindow() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        viewable.setContainer(frame.getContentPane());
    }

    public void addWindowListerner() {
    }
}
```

**Solution 4**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConcreteWindowedView view = new ConcreteWindowedView();
        Presentable presenter = new ConcretePresenter(view);
        presenter.present();
    }
}
public interface Windowable {
    public void addWindowListerner();
}
public interface Viewable {
    public void view();
    public void setContainer(Container container);
}
public interface Presentable {
    public void present();
}
public class ConcreteView implements Viewable {
    Container container;
    public ConcreteView() {
    }   
    public void setContainer(Container container) {
        this.container = container;
    }
    public void view() {
        if (container == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("Container not set.");
    }   
}
public class ConcreteWindowedView extends ConcreteView implements Windowable {
    JFrame frame;
    public ConcreteWindowedView() {
    }
    public void view() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        super.setContainer(frame.getContentPane());
        super.view();
    }        
    public void addWindowListerner() {       
    }
}
public class ConcretePresenter implements Presentable {
    Viewable viewable;
    ConcreteWindowedView concreteWindowedView;
    public ConcretePresenter(Viewable viewable) {
        this.viewable = viewable;
    }
    public ConcretePresenter(ConcreteWindowedView concreteWindowedView) {
        this.viewable = concreteWindowedView;
        this.concreteWindowedView = concreteWindowedView;
    }
    public void present() {
        // Configure presenter        
        if (concreteWindowedView != null)
            concreteWindowedView.addWindowListerner();

        this.viewable.view();     
    }           
}
```

**Thank you**

Comment: Before suggesting a solution, it would help to know what the problem is. Could you explain what problem you want to solve, rather than making us guess what it is by reading 4 long chunks of code?

Comment: I improved the question.

Comment: Too abstract, needs to be a bit more practical

Comment: The alternatives need some state to be maintained, a big "issue" in MVP is determining who "has" the state, and who "updates" the state, the presenter or the view. So, you might want to add a state for that windows, just some simple object with properties is good enough. Your examples are lacking the M(odel) in MVP.

Comment: [Regarding open-closed principle](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/ocp.pdf), "no significant program can be 100% closed," and "since closure cannot be complete, it must be strategic. That is, the designer must choose the kinds of changes against which to close his design." If you're going to worry about OCP, what kinds of changes do you want to insulate your design from? Generally, the views in MV* change more frequently than the elements of the model. Strategies aim to therefore close the Model from the openness of the Views.

Comment: Dude, don't you mean MVC??

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 is more about composition rather than adapter.
prefer Solution 1 over Solution 2 since composition is more flexible than inheritance.